# Intent data is null

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have a problem in getting photo from camera

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle()
extras.putString("photo",photo.getPath());
extras.putParcelable(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
cameraIntent.putExtras(extras);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

and there I am trying to get data:

```
case Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST: {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;
    if (data != null) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); //data always null
        SetPhotoToView(extras.getString("photo"));
    }
    break;
```

Comment: The Android SDK never talk about a intent extra with value "photo". Please read the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html and https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: @RvdK `Bundle.putString();` putting a custom value, and send to `@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {`

Answer (score 0):

try using this to get intent values

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("photo") ;
```

or

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = b.getString("name");
```

Comment: try this way to get bundle

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = b.getString("keyname");

Comment: then their is a problem with sending data as bundle

Comment: data from gallery sends ok, it's problem only for camera

Comment: log the data in onactivity result.then you can find which data is returning

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data != null) { // Before this check
```

Before check data is Null or Not get Data from Intent

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("photo");
```

and then check for data Null or Not

```
if(data != null){
    //DEAL WITH YOUR DATA
}
```